# Relation between $\min \max $ and $\max \min$

Tags: analysis

I'm currently reading a paper that uses a generalization of this formula:

$$
\min \left( \max \left( a, b \right), \max \left( c, d \right) \right)
= \max \left( \min \left( a, c \right),  \min \left( a, d \right),  \min \left( b, c \right),  \min \left( b, d \right) \right)
$$

This formula is already not straightforward to me. Are there intuitive arguments and/or a simple proof of this result or a more general form?

---

EDIT: I think that the generalized formula looks like this:
$$
\min_{i \in \{ 1..I \}} \left( \max_{j \in \{1..J_i\}} \left( a_{i, j} \right) \right)
= \max_? \left( \min_? \left( ? \right) \right)
$$
But I don't get what the "$?$" should be

Comment: if you assume $a$ is the largest and that none of the numbers are equal, the LHS is just $$\max(c, d)$$
and the RHS is $$\max(c, d, \min(b, c), \min(b, d))$$  
The RHS cannot be $b$, since $b$ can only be an argument of the $\max()$ function if it is less than one of $c$ or $d$ , So RHS = LHS. You can consider the cases in which one or more of the numbers are equal separately.

Comment: First show: $$\min(a,\max(b,c))=\max(\min(a,b),\min(a,c))$$ and $$\max(a,\min(b,c))=\min(\max(a,b)\max(a,c))$$ then deduce your formula. This is said, in mathematical terms, that the order on the real numbers forms a "distributive lattice."

Comment: In general, in a distribute lattice: $$(A\cup B)\cap (C\cup D)=(A\cap C)\cup(A\cap D)\cup(B\cap C)\cup(B\cap D)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews indeed, this way, I visualize the case with $2×2$ elements. I added the general form. Can this argument be generalized?

Comment: Sure: $$(A_1\cup \cdots \cup A_n)\cap (B_1\cup\cdots \cup B_m)=(A_1\cap B_1)\cup(A_2\cap B_1)\cup\cdots\cup(A_m\cap A_n)$$ where the right side runs through all pairs $A_i$ and $B_j.$

Comment: The general form is $$\min_{1\leq i\leq n}\left(\max_{j\in J_i}(a_{ij})\right) =\max_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in J_1\times J_2\cdot \times\cdots \times J_n}\left(\min_{i} (a_{ix_i})\right)$$

Comment: Of course, the same is true of you swap min and max in that expression.

Comment: In a complete distributive lattice (like the extended real numbers -adding $\pm\infty$) you don't even need finite sets of indices. But you'd need $\sup$ and $\inf$ instead of $\max$ and $\min.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks. I didn't know the concept of distributive lattice. If you put your comments in an answer, I will be able to validate it. It would also help me if you could apply the general formula to $\min (\max (a, b), \max(c, d, e))$